# HTTP request over GPRS and TCP dropping packets

Tags: c#, rest, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm writing a server for a biometric fingerprint device that connects via GPRS. The server receives GET and POST requests from the device and then will perform the required actions.

With the POST requests, the device should attach some additional data to the request.

The problem is, when I connect the device to the server via LAN, all the data comes through fine. When I connect via GPRS, the request body doesn't get picked up by my server.

[image: HTTP Request Comparisons]
On the left, is when I connect via LAN...the body of the message is attached.  On the right, is via GPRS, everything remains the same, however, there is no body.

[image: Wireshark bad tcp]
I ran Wireshark over the LAN and the GPRS connections. The packets, when I drill down, all have the body attached but on Wireshark, over GPRS, I get messages like above - with the out of order and RST, ACK and sometime PSH, ACK.

[image: Wireshark good tcp]

Contrasted with the LAN packets, which have none of these problems.

This is the code I'm using to read from the TCPListener

```
try
  {
    if (tcp == null)
    {
       this.tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), port);
    }
    this.tcp.Start();
    listening = true;

    while (listening)
    {
        Socket mySocket = null;

        // Blocks until a client has connected to the server
        try
        {
           mySocket = this.tcp.AcceptSocket();
           Thread.Sleep(500);

           byte[] bReceive = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];
           mySocket.Receive(bReceive);

           Analysis(bReceive, mySocket);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

   this.tcp.Stop();
```

This is the original code I got from their developer. I've tried various combinations of async, TcpClient and different socket options such as KeepAlive and DontLinger, but none seem to cure this problem.

Other than manually capturing the packets in C# to get the body, are there any C# classes I can use to read the entire request?

Comment: You are getting the 200 OK in both captures which means the HTTP layer is working properly.  In second your have the [FIN, ACK] which is the ACK for the connection closing.  So 172.31.168.217 is send close acknowledge.  It looks like the FIN (finish) keep on occurring.  I would find out why the FIN is happening.

Comment: I would get rid of the sleep and use code from msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @jdweng Do you perhaps think the out-of-order messages have anything to do with it? Thanks for the link, I'll try it out.

Comment: Possible.  Out-of-order in itself wouldn't cause an issue.  It may indicate packets being dropped due to bad hardware, but the driver in the PC reorders packets.  I think the software closed the connection when it shouldn't.  Again this could be a hardware issue, but not conclusive.  I think the right thing to do is to find out where the first FIN occurred.  I would also look to see if any SEQ are repeating due to retires.  I don't know how well you understand TCP specification and the c# code.  I'm kind of an expert.  Worked for 5 years in testing TCP.

Comment: @jdweng What I don't understand is, even though the packets are being dropped and the software may be closing the connection, WireShark can still reassemble the packets and get the data I'm looking for, but in C# I can't.

Comment: There is a know race condition when a TCP connection is closed.  The Close has to be ACK.  So when one end of connection closes connection the other end can still send.  The send will not get ACK since the connection is closing.  Then the send may get resent since an ACK was not received.  Also you can have both end close a connection at same time which cause different issues.  You sometimes get connection half open and half closed due to race conditions so you  can send but not receive.  Sometimes it is useful to check from cms.exe > NetStat -a which will show connection status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the server as async using the code in the link below. This is so I could implement the logic to reread the stream if the end of the stream hasn't been reached. I just had to change the end of file condition for my circumstances.

Here's a link to the article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Answer (score 2):

TCP is a stream oriented protocol. Everybody knows that but a lot of developers do not consider that when they implement a TCP receiver.

When a send calls `Send("ABCDEFG")` and client calls `Receive(buffer)` the `buffer` may contain `"ABCDEFG"` or `"ABCD"` or `"A"` or whatever substring from original data that begins with `"A"`. TCP is a stream of data without any information about message boundaries.

The receiver that needs to receive a message with a length that is unknown during the compile time (like an HTTP request) must contain a logic that receives the header, parse it and than waits till complete message is received.

But you don't need to implement it yourself. C# has the class `HttpServer` that already contains this logic. Moreover there are libraries with REST support. It is reinventing wheel to implement a REST server and start with `TcpListener` and sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried using the HttpListener class, however it didn't seem to want to work over LAN, my software has to support LAN and GPRS. Over GPRS, I connect to the server with a URI, on LAN, I connect to the server via an IP address. I couldn't think of how to resolve the fact that the TCPListener takes and IP address and the HttpListener takes an a URI and it seems they're mutually exclusive. But, as you say, does feel like I'm trying to reinvent the wheel. I'll try your advice.

Comment: The class `HttpServer` does not depend on physical layer and it works correctly with LAN, GPRS and in general with any type of physical network. When you create it you need to specify a port where the server listens and it listens on all interfaces that the host has.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. Please see my second comment to jdweng - I think at the end of the day, that's my biggest concern...if the packets are being sent, why are none of the C# classes performing the reassembly?

Comment: TCP is not a service for delivering packets. It is s stream service. So C# socket cannot perform reassembly because TCP does not have anything like message/packet boundaries. Well there are packets at lower layers but they are not visible for TCP application. Application level protocol must reassemble messages from the stream and `HttpServer` class does that.